# Angular SweetAlert2, alert closes after the ShowValidationError is displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert2

I am using SweetAlert2 (https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to verify user's password before an action is taken. My promise works well, verifying the password in the server and returning true or false.
When password is correct, alert is displayed confirming the successful password verification.
However, when the password is incorrect, the sweetalert stops and closes without executing the action. Not executing the action is the expected behaivour, however I want it to stay displaying the message to alert the user about the incorrect password entered. The swal.showValidationError seems to work fine but the alert doesn't stay active for the user to reenter a password.

Can anybody take a look at the code below and point me in the right direction?. Thank you in advance

```
$scope.confirmPublish = function(newsFormEdit, publish, trigger, updateReason){   
// Request password confirmation before Publishing a News. 
// After password is successfully confirmed the event is triggered    
    swal({
      title: $translate.instant("news_confirmPublish_title"),
      text: $translate.instant("news_confirmPublish_text"),
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: $translate.instant("confirmPublish_confirmBtn"),
      cancelButtonText: $translate.instant("confirmPublish_cancelBtn"),
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
      cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
      buttonsStyling: true
    }).then(function () {
        swal({
          title: 'Enter password to run ajax request',
          input: 'password',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
          showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
          preConfirm: (pass) => {
              return promisedPost('./service/verify_password.php', { pass })
                    .then(results => {
                        results = JSON.parse(results);
                        if (results.value === false) {
                            swal.showValidationError('Incorrect Password.');
                        } else {
                            return results;    
                        }
                    });
          },
          allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
        })
            .then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
              if (trigger === "create") {
                $scope.createNews(newsFormEdit, publish);
              } else {
                $scope.updateNews(newsFormEdit, publish, updateReason);
              }
            swal({
              type: 'success',
              title: 'Ajax request finished!'
            });
            }
        })
    }, function (dismiss) {
      if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
        swal(
          'Cancelled',
          'Publish of news has been cancelled!',
          'error'
        )
      }
    })};
```